# JpaSpecificationExecutor's method 'findBy()' does not use Sort object from provided Pageable object

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

`JpaSpecificationExecutor`'s method `findBy()` does not use `Sort` object from provided `Pageable` object.

I try to use `findBy()` method of `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to be able mixing specification and projection, e.g.:

```
var someSort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "someFiled");
var somePageable = PageRequest.of(0, 100, someSort);

someRepository.findBy(someSpecification, q -> q.as(SomeProjection.class).page(somePageable));
```

But the code above ignores my custom sorting.

I can see from the source code, that it really doesn't use Sort object from provided Pageable object.
`FetchableFluentQueryBySpecification`'s `page()` method uses `createSortedAndProjectedQuery()` method under the hood which uses default sorting(`Sort.unsorted()`) instead of provided one.

Everything works as expected If I use '`sortBy()`' method with provided custom sorting object, but why should I provide `Sort` object separately instead of just providing it with Pageable object?

Should it work like this or it's a bug ?